# how to define directory to install

Tags: php, git, composer-php

i have the following problem and hopefully someone can help me.
and hopefully there is a solution. i could not find something in the documentation.

i have a private git repository that i want to include via composer. everything works fine so far.

but: i want composer to "install" a subdirectory instead of the root node.

for example: the structure looks like

```
/ 
/tests
/src
/help
```

now i want composer to "install" the /src directory into /vendor/name/project

is this even possible?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't `/vendor/name/project/src` the default?

Comment: nope. / is default

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question and overlooked the `install` bit.

Comment: You need to create a custom installer. https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md  If not, you can use custom scripts and run the git pull | git clone https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md

Comment: thanks. i will check and try it.